# Integration of random images as email signature

Tags: wordpress, email, outlook, script-tag

I'm looking for a function that will allow me to select my site from a folder of images in the WordPress installation.

I have 5 images of the same size named 1.png, 2.png and so on in the folder `https: //domain.tld/_wordpress/wp-content/uploads/images`. I would like to attach this to a mail in Outlook via HTML (or another script).

The way to integrate individual images is known. However, one of these 5 images should be selected at random. It is about advertising and more understanding of voluntary work.

How can I do something like that?

PS: I found this code, but it doesn't work.

```html
img src="https://www.domain.tld/_wordpress/wp-content/uploads/images/random/image _<?php $random = rand(1,2); echo $random; ?>.png" alt="Random Image" height="201" width="600" /
```

Comment: man you want choose randomly with php or you are inside a email template in say outlook, gmail?

Comment: Outlook doesnt execute scripts so you cant. Since you use wordpress send dynamic emails with wp_email().

Comment: @billybadass - yes, inside a email template in outlook or thunderbird or so.

Comment: @MartinMirchev - how can i send mails via wordpress? i use wp_mail for send mails to from wordpress to my own mail adress, because wordpress standalone not send all mails

Comment: @ThomasD. wp is sending emails based on events. If someone make a registration for example. You can send emails based on cron job. SO depends on how and when you want to push that email. If you go to WP doc you can see some examples - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/ where your body can be dynamic to get random images from a dir.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an option would also be sufficient to rename a file accordingly every day under Wordpress. 001.png becomes 1.png and today's 1.png becomes 001 etc.

Then you could have a fixed link, so that the graphic is given a name corresponding to the graphic on the server side every day.
It should just be automated somehow.
Unfortunately, I have no idea how or whether something like this can be implemented.